# Nested Classes in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, nested

So I am trying to display the class `col-md-3` for larger screens and the class `pure-container` on smaller screens with the side menu. The contents of the side menu should display regularly on larger screens without the `hamburger` pan but on smaller screens it should be contained in the `hamburger` menu.

The larger screen size works fine with the content, and the smaller screen size displays the side menu but it's missing the content, any suggestions? I have tried to include `content visible-xs visible-sm` for the `pure-drawer` but it doesn't work, I also tried media queries.

here is the code.

```
<div class="col-md-3 content visible-md visible-lg">
  <?php  include_once 'helper/block_news_list.php'; ?>
</div>

<!-- Begining of the pure-drawer -->
<div class="pure-container" data-effect="pure-effect-push">
  <input type="checkbox" id="pure-toggle-left" class="pure-toggle" data-toggle="left" />
  <label class="pure-toggle-label" for="pure-toggle-left" data-toggle-label="left"><span class="pure-toggle-icon"></span></label>

  <nav class="pure-drawer" data-position="left">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p style="padding: 10px 20px; margin: 0;">
      <?php include_once 'helper/block_news_list.php'; ?>
    </p>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you use `include_once` which prevents the same code to be rendered twice. As the result, your `pure_drawer` is actually empty.

You can change

```
<?php include_once 'helper/block_news_list.php'; ?>
```

to

```
<?php include 'helper/block_news_list.php'; ?>
```

in order to render news list in both containers.

Comment: Yes!! That worked! I have been looking everywhere for this, thank you so much! I guess i didn't consider that. Much Much thanks. Really.